# Pytest is in PATH but not found

Tags: command-line, bash, python, paths

I've installed pytest for python testing, but I get `No such file or directory` error when simply trying to run it from a project folder.

It's in a location that should be accessible through the `PATH` variable, but (to the best of my ability to describe the problem) isn't being 'found'. For some reason when I type 'pytest' my shell is looking to the wrong location; if I specify the location then pytest will run fine.

Looking in `/usr/bin`

```
kirk@kirk:~/develop/foo$ pytest
bash: /usr/bin/pytest: No such file or directory
```

It's actually in `/usr/local/bin`, which is part of the path, and works when I explicitly call that location.

```
kirk@kirk:~/develop/foo$ whereis pytest
pytest: /usr/local/bin/pytest

kirk@kirk:~/develop/foo$ echo $PATH
/home/kirk/bin:/home/kirk/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
    /usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

kirk@kirk:~/develop/foo$ /usr/local/bin/pytest
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.0.5, py-1.4.32, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /home/kirk/develop/foo, inifile: pytest.ini
collected 0 items 

========================= no tests ran in 0.00 seconds =========================
```

What can cause this behavior?

Comment: Try `hash -r pytest`

Comment: Add this in the `.bashrc` file `export PATH=/usr/local/bin/pytest/bin:$PATH` and see if you can access it

Comment: @steeldriver that worked - what did it do?

Comment: See explanation below

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To avoid searching your `PATH` every time an executable command is called, `bash` saves previously used commands in a lookup table, or *hash*.

If you subsequently move the executable or install another version elsewhere on the `PATH`, it is sometimes necessary to force the shell to 'forget' the old location - running `help hash` in the bash shell:

```
     -r                forget all remembered locations
```

or to forget just a single command

```
hash -d <command>
```

In this case, you seem to have had a previous version of `pytest` at `/usr/bin/pytest`: running `hash -r pytest` forced the shell to re-examine your `PATH` and find its current location `/usr/local/bin/pytest`.