# GDB not available after "make install" unless a new terminal is opened

Tags: command-line, gdb

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and development on Linux in general. After building GDB from source (pre-installed the dependencies):

```
$ git clone git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git
$ CD binutils-gdb
$ ./Configure
$ Make
$ Make Install
```

I tried:

```
$ gdb
```

and got the following:

```
bash: /usr/bin/gdb: No such file or directory
```

Opened up a new terminal, tried running GDB again, and got the expected output of:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1.50.20180123-git...
```

Wondering why it only worked after opening a new terminal.

Comment: It's going to be hard to say for sure - possibly the shell had cached the previous location (see for example [Pytest is in PATH but not found](https://askubuntu.com/a/861386/178692))

Comment: You do strange things, GDB [is packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=gdb).