# Why does which show me one path for an executable, but when I run the executable bash thinks it's in a different path?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to run doxygen. When I type it at the bash prompt I get the following:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/doxygen: No such file or directory
```

Yet when I try `which doxygen` I get:

```
/usr/bin/doxygen
```

I though `which` was supposed to identify which executable would be run if it were entered at the command line. Does anyone know what is going on here and how I can fix it so I can run `doxygen` without specifying its prefix?

I had doxygen 1.18.1 installed and attempted to install the latest version (not from the repo), which didn't go well so I removed it. The latest version had put its executable in `/usr/local/bin'. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in the first place.

`type -a doxygen` results in `doxygen is /usr/bin/doxygen`.

My path is `/usr/local/lib:/usr/share/code:/home/mark/bin:/home/mark/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`, but there is no `doxygen` in /usr/local/bin.

Comment: How did you install `doxygen`?

Comment: Didi you install  to doxygen? sudo apt-get install doxygen
 sudo apt-get install doxygen-gui

Comment: So running it with `/usr/bin/doxygen` it works and with only `doxygen` it doesn't, or did you try to run it with `/usr/local/bin/doxygen` here? Do you have `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH`? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: Please Edit your Question and show us `type -a doxygen`.

Comment: Possibly related to [Pytest is in PATH but not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861376/pytest-is-in-path-but-not-found)