# Fail to invoke emacs from terminal

Tags: emacs

I installed emacs25.2.2

```
me@me:~$ /usr/bin/emacs --version
GNU Emacs 25.2.2
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of GNU Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.
```

but, I cannot invoke it directly

```
me@me:~$ emacs
bash: /usr/local/bin/emacs: No such file or directory
```

emacs is within the $PATH

```
me@me:~$ emacs
bash: /usr/local/bin/emacs: No such file or directory
me@me:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I installed emacs 26.1 and uninstalled it from the source using 'make uninstall' since it was painful to tackle errors of gnutls

How could I invoke the current version of emacs directly?

Comment: Likely related: [Pytest is in PATH but not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861376/pytest-is-in-path-but-not-found)

Comment: ty, restart the machine and it was rescued @steeldriver