# Terminal trying to use a file that does not match which

Tags: cuda

The output of `which nvcc` gives me:

```
/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin/nvcc
```

However, when I execute `nvcc --version`, I get

```
-bash: /usr/bin/nvcc: No such file or directory
```

So `which` is telling me it is using the nvcc inside `/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin`, but the actual `nvcc` command points to `/usr/bin`. Shouldn't the `nvcc` command point to `/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin`?

Comment: What does `type -a nvcc` say? Possibly your shell has hashed a previous location of the command - see for example [Pytest is in PATH but not found](https://askubuntu.com/a/861386/178692)

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be what happened because restarting my computer fixed it. I assume restarting my terminal would have fixed it too, but my computer needed a restart anyways.