# "cmake --version" points to /usr/bin/cmake while "which cmake" points to /usr/local/bin

Tags: paths, cmake

I am trying to upgrade cmake on my linux computer. Here is the command I used

```
sudo apt purge --auto-remove cmake
```

After downloading and extracted cmake-3.13.3.tar.gz

```
./bootstrap
make 
sudo make install
```

when I did `cmake --version` it returns

```
bash: /usr/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
```

However no cmake executable exists in `/usr/bin` and strangely `which cmake` returns

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake
```

which is where cmake actually is.

My `$path` is

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

How do I have the command `cmake` point to `/usr/local/bin/cmake`?

Comment: If `/usr/bin/cmake` was removed only recently, then it's possible your current shell has hashed the old value. See [Pytest is in PATH but not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861376/pytest-is-in-path-but-not-found/861386#861386) for a similar case.

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed it. If you want to make this the answer i will accept it.

Comment: sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/cmake /usr/bin/