# "-bash: /usr/bin/cmake: No such file or directory"

Tags: apt, bash, software-installation, cmake

I `apt-get` removed default CMake and build CMake from source and installed the new version into `/usr/local` . But the `cmake` comannd does not works.

I've tried following commands:

```bsh
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ sudo ldconfig
$ which cmake
/usr/local/bin/cmake
$ /usr/local/bin/cmake --version
cmake version 3.18.4
$ cmake --version
-bash: /usr/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
```

I can create a soft link `/usr/bin/cmake` to `/usr/local/bin/cmake` , but I'm curious about why the `cmake` command obstinately point to the former?

Additional Information:

```bsh
$ dpkg -l | grep cmake
rc  cmake-data  3.10.2-1ubuntu2.18.04.1  all  CMake data files (modules, templates and documentation)

$ apt-cache policy cmake
cmake:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.10.2-1ubuntu2.18.04.1
  Version table:
     3.10.2-1ubuntu2.18.04.1 500
        500 http://[INTRANET]/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     3.10.2-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://[INTRANET]/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

which [INTRANET] is a private source of a company.

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep cmake` with `apt-cache policy cmake` to the question.

Comment: Are you sure the old path is not simply hashed by your shell? see for example [Pytest is in PATH but not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861376/pytest-is-in-path-but-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

you should run

```
hash -r
```

your terminal just hashed the old command and is giving a problem, this will reset the hashes